# c++ make command unrecognized command line option error

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

While compilation getting those errors

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wnull-dereference'
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wduplicated-cond'
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wnull-dereference'
```

I am using some image environment and seems that something is missing
Tried several solutions:

1. adding to Dockerfile

   yum -y install centos-release-scl
   yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc devtoolset-7-gcc-c++
   scl enable devtoolset-7 -- bash
2. adding to Dockerfile:

   wget http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/sclo/aarch64/rh/Packages/d/devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.aarch64.rpm
   yum -y localinstall devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.2.1-1.el7.sc1.aarch64.rpm
   Nothing helped so far

Comment: Please show the output from `c++ --version` .

Comment: @G.M. c++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Comment: its a very old version of gcc so probably doesn't have the same options as a newer version

Comment: @AlanBirtles any suggestions how ?

Comment: either don't use those options or use a newer version of gcc

Comment: I'm afraid that, in order to [ask a good, useful and answerable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you need to understand and communicate what exactly is happening *inside* the Docker container. What system is in there? What software are you compiling? What is the compiler?
After figuring it out, it will be clear that the question is about a specific software plus specific Docker image. And yes, in the end, that version of gcc will not compile that Makefile.